# How to solve $e^x=\pi^x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I try to solve $e^x=\pi^x$ and so far, only the following is natural, but does not yield a correct answer:

Put the natural log on each part:

$ln(e^x)=ln(\pi^x)$

$x\cdot ln(e)=x\cdot ln(\pi)$

but:

$ln(e)\ne ln(\pi)$

So we have a contradiction.

Which approach would be correct, and why is the natural logarithm not giving correct results here?

An alternative would be to use the series form

$e^x=\big(\frac{1}{n!}\big)^x$ and the Leibniz formula for $\pi=4arctan(1)$ and get:

$\big(\frac{1}{n!}\big)^x=4arctan(1)^x$

$x\cdot ln\big(\frac{1}{n!}\big)=x\cdot ln(4arctan(1))$

Take the partial sum of the first 10 terms and get an approximation:

$x\cdot ln\big(\frac{9864101}{3628800}\big)=x\cdot ln(4arctan(1))$

But here also, we get a problem. How can I find both real and complex solutions?

Comment: *Hint:* Thou shalt not divide by zero. – Btw, which “correct answer” did you expect?

Comment: How about dividing both sides by, say, the right-hand side...? $$\frac{e^x}{\pi^x}=1$$ seems easy to simplify.

Comment: I couldn't say how to do this algebraically, but anything to the power 0 = 1, so if you take x=0, it would result in 1=1.

Comment: @Striker Anything – except zero! That's because zero to 'any' power is zero, and it makes contradiction between $0^x=0$ and $y^0=1$ at $(x,y)=(0,0)$; hence a power $0^0$ is generally undefined (except some specific applications). More at e.g. Wikipedia [Zero to the power of zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).

Comment: @CiaPan Here , we do not have the $0^0$-case.

Comment: @CiaPan thanks for telling me! That's pretty interesting, I never thought about it

Comment: @Peter I know. However, the statement by Striker was too general, and I felt it'd be good to correct it despite the fact the specific case does not apply to _this_ MSE problem.

Answer (score 3):

We have $x=0$, hence you can't perform the division.

$$x\cdot (\ln (e) - \ln (\pi)) = 0$$

Hence $x=0$ or $\ln(e)-\ln(\pi)=0$. Since $\ln(e)-\ln(\pi)\ne0$, we conclude that $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

The natural logarithm actually does give a correct result:
$$x\ln e = x\ln\pi$$
makes
$$x(\ln e - \ln\pi)=0$$
which is equivalent to
$$x=0 \text{   or   } \ln e - \ln\pi=0$$

As the second equality obviously doesn't hold, the only result is $x=0$.